# Camel Http4 2.12.2: "httpClientConfigurer" cannot be inferred from endpointUri

Tags: scala, http, properties, https, apache-camel

I'm using scala akka-camel with http4 component (2.12.2 version).
I'm creating a Camel producer with endpoint:

```
def endpointUri = "https4://host-path" + 
     "?bridgeEndpoint=true" +
     "&httpClientConfigurer=#configurer" + 
     "&clientConnectionManager=#manager"
```

where `configurer` is an `HttpClientConfigurer` registered in Camel context registry (the same principle applies to `manager`).

When I'm sending a CamelMessage to that endpoint I can see at akka logs this:

```
DEBUG o.a.c.component.http4.HttpComponent - Creating endpoint uri https4://host-path?bridgeEndpoint=true&httpClientConfigurer=#configurer&clientConnectionManager=#manager
DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: clientConnectionManager on bean: Endpoint["https4://host-path?bridgeEndpoint=true&httpClientConfigurer=#configurer&clientConnectionManager=#manager"] with value: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager@3da3d36f
DEBUG o.a.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport - Configured property: bridgeEndpoint on bean: Endpoint["https4://host-path?bridgeEndpoint=true&httpClientConfigurer=#configurer&clientConnectionManager=#manager"] with value: true
INFO  o.a.c.component.http4.HttpComponent - Registering SSL scheme https on port 443
INFO  o.a.c.component.http4.HttpComponent - Registering SSL scheme https4 on port 443
```

So httpClientConfigurer is not configured and I don't know why it's ignoring this parameter. I've been looking for any related issue at Apache  Camel issue tracker but I have found nothing similar.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use the debugger in this class: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=blob;f=components/camel-http4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpEndpoint.java;h=2ef06b8bc54ba9f88e86ea5e99391621af68f698;hb=HEAD and see what's going on. Also, if you are using SSL, shouldn't you be using `https4` instead of `http4s`?

Comment: I'll try to debug that class downloading the sources as well. About `http4s`, it's just a misprint, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it's resolved. I haven't used the none of `clientConnectionManager` or `httpClientConfigurer`. I've used `SSLContextParams` and a trait called TlsConfigurer that is meant to be mixed-in with a Producer.

I want to use different X509 certificates, so, as Camel suggests:

> **Important**: Only one instance of org.apache.camel.util.jsse.SSLContextParameters is supported per HttpComponent. If you need to use 2 or more different instances, you need to define a new HttpComponent per instance you need.

Therefore, TlsConfigurer `configure` method must be able to get a `http4` component instance from camel context and then apply the SSLContextParams and add the modified instance as a new component to camel context.

This is how it looks:

```scala
import org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent
import org.apache.camel.util.jsse._

trait TlsConfigurer { 
    self: {val camel: akka.camel.Camel} =>

    def configure(
        componentName: String, 
        keyStorePath:String, 
        trustStorePath:String, 
        password: String) {

        val ksp = new KeyStoreParameters
        ksp.setResource(keystorePath)
        ksp.setPassword(password)

        val kmp = new KeyManagersParameters
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp)
        kmp.setKeyPassword(password)

        val scp = new SSLContextParameters
        scp.setKeyManagers(kmp)

        val httpComponent = 
           camel.context.getComponent("http4",classOf[HttpComponent])
        httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp)

        camel.context.addComponent(componentName, httpComponent) 

    }

}
```

This way I can create two different end-points: `http-client1://...` and `http-client2://...` and manage their certificates in a separate way.

Answer (score 0):

httpClientConfigurer is not set to the HttpEndpoint by using IntrospectionSupport, so you don't see the debug log. 
I think we about to find out the configurer is called when you add some log in the customer configurer.

Comment: That logging issue may be true, but the thing is, I've tried with `camel 2.8.4` and it works perfectly, but with the latest version, httpClientConfigurer seems not being properly configured. I got an error that says:

   `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: We upgrade the httpclient 4 version after camel-2.8.4. Can you double check if the configurer code can work with httpclient 4.2.5?

Comment: I downgraded my `httpclient`version as you mentioned, from `4.3.2` to `4.2.5` but it still doesn't work. However, I don't get the same error. Now I get this: `[ERROR] [02/11/2014 09:36:59.395] [MyTestAkkaSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://MyTestAkkaSystem/user/$a/$a] Failure(akka.camel.AkkaCamelException: peer not authenticated) (of class akka.actor.Status$Failure)`